# Having parameter syntactic sugar in scala

Tags: scala, parameters, syntactic-sugar

I have a bit of syntactic sugar for operations that depends on an object :

```
case class EllipticOperand (p : Point)
{
  def + (q : => Point) = curve.sum(p,q)
  def * (n : => BigInt) = curve.times(p,n)
}
implicit def PointToOperand(p : Point) = EllipticOperand(p)

case class EllipticMultiplier (n : BigInt)
{
def * (p : => Point) = curve.times(p,n)
}
implicit def BigIntToOperand (n : BigInt) = EllipticMultiplier(n)
```

I would like to encapsulate in some `class SyntacticSugar[Point](curve : main.Curve[Point])` to use it in other classes definitions without having to copy/paste it.

I tried to use it that way :

```
val sugar = new util.SyntacticSugar(curve)
import sugar._
```

However, this doesn't work, I can't use `+` and `*` after.

Comment: why not trait that you will mix in to some other class?

Comment: The problem is, `trait`s dont support parameters and my syntactic sugar depends on a specific curve each time.
Thanks by the way.

Comment: You defined the class `SyntacticSugar` like this: `class SyntacticSugar[Point](curve : main.Curve[Point])`? So `Point` in de code snippet above is not a class but a type parameter?

Comment: Well, `Point` is indeed a type-parameter, but `curve` is an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I implement it the way you suggest it just works...

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)

trait Curve[T] {
  def sum(p: T, q: T): T
  def times(p: T, n: Int): T
}

// dummy implementation
class PointCurve extends Curve[Point] {
  override def sum(p: Point, q: Point) = Point(p.x+q.x, p.y+q.y)
  override def times(p: Point, n: Int) = Point(p.x*n, p.y*n)
}


object util {
  class SyntacticSugar[T](curve: Curve[T]){
    case class EllipticOperand(p: T){
      def +(q: =>T) = curve.sum(p, q)
      def *(n: =>Int) = curve.times(p,n)
    }
    implicit def point2Operand(p: T) = EllipticOperand(p)
  }
}
```

Now you can use `+` and `*` as operators on a `Point`:

```
scala> val sugar = new util.SyntacticSugar(new PointCurve)
sugar: util.SyntacticSugar[Point] = util$SyntacticSugar@4ed4b486

scala> import sugar._
import sugar._

scala> Point(1,2) + Point(2,3)
res0: Point = Point(3,5)

scala> Point(1,2) * 3
res1: Point = Point(3,6)
```

Comment: It doesn't work with me, is it because it is in a different file ? If so it is a problem cause I won't putting all my classes in the same one.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to have all the classes in the same file. Only `SyntacticSugar`, `EllipticOperand` and the `point2Operand` method must be in the same file, since `SyntacticSugar` is the enclosing class of the other two. 
What kind of errors do you get? At which lines of code?

Comment: I get `overloaded method value * with alternatives (...) cannot be applied to (Point) a * p` where `a` is a `BigInt` and `p` a point. (I added the syntactic sugar for `BigInt` in my first message).

Comment: I think you are doing `5 * Point(1,2)` but for this to work you should do `BigInt(5) * Point(1,2)`. The _really_ strange thing is that this still doesn't work... `implicitly[BigInt=>{def *(p: =>Point): Point }]` finds the appropriate implicit view, but the compiler doesn't apply it when necessary. I think you should open a separate question for this problem, cause this is pretty strange.

Comment: It seems that if you change the by-name parameter to a by-value parameter (remove the =>) the implicit conversion does work. Still doesn't really explain why it works for `Point * BigInt` with by-name parameters but not for `BigInt * Point`... Looks like the combination of type parameters and by-name parameters confuses the compiler...

Comment: By the way, if you want to be able to use the notation `5 * Point(1,2)` without explicitly constructing a `BigInt` you should add a third implicit def: `implicit def int2Operand (n: Int) = EllipticMultiplier(n)`

Comment: Well, there is already one for `Int`, so it shouldn't be the cause of the problem. Plus, if I just copy the body of the class `SyntacticSugar`, it just works. So it is strange if I ever need to change my implementation.